# Accrued interest on RFR Floating Rate Note

Tags: fixed-income, bond, floating-rate

On fixed rate bonds and IBOR based floating rate notes the next cashflow is known **definitively** in advance, therefore the accrued interest for a given settlement date is a trivial calculation typically following something like:

$$ accrued = cashflow * \frac{settlement - period start}{period end - period start} $$

But for RFR FRNs the cashflow depends on all of the RFR published fixings within the coupon period.
This creates two issues:

1. Estimating the fixings mid-period is subjective and depends on curve construction and curve calibrating instruments which differs across counterparties, so the accrued would be subjective.
2. Those estimates for the cashflow might change during the day leading to one purchase with one estimate, or recorded amount, of accrued interest and a sale with a different estimate or recorded amount. This would presumably be a nightmare to coordinate settlement with different amounts of accrued on the same bond in the same notional on the same settlement day.

Thus I'm assuming this cannot be the case and there is an official formula. Does anyone have any term sheet, link or first hand knowledge?

Comment: I must be confused - what difficulties arise hrre, that don't arise in a traditional overnight index swap?

Comment: Related question, no answers yet https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/51836

Comment: OIS are not securities that are processed through a settlement system. A traditional bond trades with a clean price and settles on that price plus accrued interest. If you were, for example, terminating an OIS part way through the period the two counterparties would explicitly derive a cashflow (as the NPV price) and that would be the settlement value. But an RFR FRN should have a clean price plus accrued.

Comment: Thanks I understand now. ARRC paper https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/Microsites/arrc/files/2021/users-guide-to-sofr2021-update.pdf discussed several approaches, I believe most SOFR FRNs use 2 business days "lookback with no observarion shift".

Comment: This spreadsheet https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/Microsites/arrc/files/2020/ARRC-BLWG-Example-Lookback-without-Observation-Shift.xlsx illustrates accrued calculation with 5 business days lookback.

Comment: Yes with those links it seems that say for a quarterly FRN, where you are 1 month into a period the accrued is calculated by using the available fixings to the settlement date and compounding up over that 1montha and using that as a the accrued amount. This is a bit different to regular fixed rate bonds or historical IBOR bonds, but marginally so and it becomes a deteministic problem with available data which is suitable for settlement systems.

Comment: Also, i dont think you need to project the entire next cashflow. You only need the coupon amount accrued until the settlement date.

Comment: This prospectus https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/316709/000119312521082222/d73686d424b5.htm page S-15 says: "“Interest Payment Determination Date” means the date two U.S. Government Securities Business Days before each interest payment date."